# How can I make TFS 2013 make a new "merge commit" on "complete merge" button press

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

We are in the process of changing our code review process and want to use the TFS integrated pull request feature for that.

I have TFS 2013.5 installed and we use git as Source Control for the TFS;

workflow is as follows:

- team member gets a task assigned
- team member implements the task in a seperate branch
- team member creates a "pull request" (in the TFS Web-Area under  => CODE => Pull Requests => "New Pull Request" (choosing the seperate branch he worked on and master branch)
- one member of the team approves and presses thumbs up
- the requester presses "complete merge"

now, what happens is that TFS merges the branch to master. but he tries to keep a single branch line it seems. (Thats at least what its called if you merge 2 branches via git extensions). in git extensions there is also a radio button "always create a new merge commit".

what we would want to do is that TFS on merging also always creates a new merge commit.

is that possible? any experiences with that?

thanks in advance

Comment: It does create a merge commit (as opposed to squashing or rebasing)...  Why do you think that it does not?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no option  anywhere to choose one way or the other.

And for **TFS2013 the default is a fast-forward merge**. You can see a talk from this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/06/10/conduct-a-git-pull-request-on-visual-studio-online/).

> **Carlos Muñoz Rodriguez**: Is it possible to create a merge commit
>   instead of fast forward when hitting the merge button?
>
> **mmitrik**: @Carlos – Not yet, but we're considering adding a –no-ff
>   option that can be set to require that a pull request is always
>   merged.  We might also make this a setting at the branch or repo
>   level.  If you added a suggestion on visualstudio.uservoice.com that
>   would help us track the need for this.

If you want to use  `--no-ff` by default, you can **use VS Team Service.**

> Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded  ·  November
>   25, 2015
>
> We recently made a change to **cause all PR merges to be performed with
>   the —no-ff option.** Some of the comments below indicate a desire to
>   choose between no-ff and ff merges, and while we don’t plan to bring
>   back the ff merge option, we do have work underway to enable squash
>   merging as an option. In the future, we also plan to add rebase
>   options to rebase a topic branch onto the head of the target branch.

More details you can check the link:[no-fastforward merge from pullrequest](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6073200-no-fastforward-merge-from-pullrequest) from UserVoice